# Why finite subgroups of a virtually cyclic group have bounded order?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an infinite, virtually cyclic group, i.e., $G$ has an infinite cyclic subgroup $H$ of finite index.

I have a question: Why is there a finite bound on the orders of finite subgroups of $G$?

**What I tried**: If $G$ is finite, then $|G|$ is a bound on the orders of its subgroups. But I don't know why is true about an infinite virtually cyclic group.

Comment: Every finite group is virtually cyclic: the trivial subgroup is cyclic and has finite index.

Comment: Also, please provide *context.*

Comment: @Shaun Okay, sure.

Comment: Dear @LeeMosher Can I ask a relevant question here?

Comment: Just to point out that the same statement holds for any virtually polycyclic group, because it has the maximum condition on subgroups (i.e., there is no infinite chain of subgroups each properly contained in the next).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to realize that $G$ not only has a finite index infinite cyclic subgroup $H$, but in addition it has a finite index infinite cyclic *normal* subgroup $N$, namely $N = \bigcap_{g \in G} g H g^{-1}$: it is a general group theory exercise that for any group $G$ and any finite index subgroup $H < G$, the subgroup $N$ as defined is finite index and normal; and since $N < H$ it follows that $N$ is cyclic.

So suppose now that $C \subset G$ is a subgroup whose order is larger than the order of the finite quotient group $G/N$. The kernel of the homomorphism $C \mapsto G/N$ is therefore nonempty. But the kernel of that homomorphism is $C \cap N$, and so any nontrivial element of the kernel has infinite order, implying that the subgroup $C$ is infinite.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect explanation. I got it completely.

Comment: Can I ask a relevant question here?

Comment: If you have a substantial followup question, the best thing is to ask it in a new post. Otherwise, the only site users who will see it are me and you and whatever small number of folk happen to stumble across it.

Comment: You are right. I'll ask my question in a new post. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I asked my relevant question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516243/the-number-of-infinite-retracts-of-a-virtually-cyclic-group?noredirect=1#comment9484656_4516243

Comment: Could you please tell me how to define the homomorphism $C\to G/N$ in your answer? By $g\mapsto gN$?

Comment: For any group $G$ and any normal subgroup $N$, there is a standard *quotient* homomorphism $G \mapsto G/N$ given by the formula $g \mapsto gN$. Also, for any subgroup of $G$ and any subgroup $C < G$, any homomorphism defined on $G$ can be *restricted* to obtain a homomorphism on $C$. So yes, the homomorphism $C \mapsto G/N$, which is the restriction of the quotient homomorphism, is given by $g \mapsto gN$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.