# Is there a finite bound on the indexes of infinite retracts of an infinite virtually cyclic group $G$?

Tags: group-theory, retraction

Let $G$ be an infinite, virtually cyclic group, i.e., $G$ has an infinite cyclic subgroup $H$ of finite index (or equivalently, it contains a finite index infinite cyclic normal subgroup $N$).

By a retract of $G$ I mean a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that there exists a normal subgroup $L$ with $G=K\ltimes L$.

**Question:** Is there a finite bound on the indexes of  infinite retracts of an infinite virtually cyclic group $G$?

**What I've tried:** Let $K$ be an infinite retract of $G$. By definition, there is a normal subgroup $L$ with $G=K\ltimes L$. I don't know how to show that  $L$ is a finite subgroup of $G$. If so, then the index of $K$ in $G$ becomes finite.  Since finite subgroups of $G$ have bounded order (in fact, the order of the finite quotient group $G/N$ is a finite bound on the orders of finite subgroups of $G$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516075/why-finite-subgroups-of-a-virtually-cyclic-group-have-bounded-order))), then its infinite retracts have finite bounded index.

Comment: Again, all finite groups are virtually cyclic because the trivial group has finite index, and it is cyclic.

Comment: Dear @Shaun , Yes, I know. But I don't understand what you mean. By a virtually cyclic group here I mean infinite ones.

Comment: Then you should specify you mean the group to be infinite. As it stands, "virtually cyclic [. . .] i.e. [. . .] infinite", etc., is just wrong.

Comment: @Shaun You are right. I'll do it.

Comment: If $G = H \rtimes N$ is virtually cyclic and $N$ is infinite, then $H$ is finite (you said that you knew that). So if $H$ is infinite then $N$ is finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt I made a mistake in notations. If $G$ is virtually cyclic, then there is  a finite index infinite cyclic normal subgroup  $N$. Now my question is that: if $K$ is an infinite retract of $G$, then is $|G:K|$  finite? In fact, is there a finite bound on $|G:K|$ when $K$ is an infinite retract?

Comment: You seem to have just replaced $H$ by $K$ - what is the point of that? In your post you used $N$ with two different meanings.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right. Let me edit it and ask my question clearly.

Comment: @DerekHolt I've just edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is virtually cyclic with infinite cyclic normal subgroup $N$ and $|G:N|$ finite. Suppose also that $G = K \ltimes L$.

Now $|L:L \cap N| \le |G:N|$ is finite. So, if $L$ is infinite, then so is $L \cap N$, and hence $|N:L \cap N|$ is finite, and so $|G:L \cap N|$ is finite, and so $|G:L|$ is finite. But $G/L \cong K$, so $K$ is finite.

Hence, if $K$ is infinite, then $L$ must be finite.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It had some good points for me. I appreciate it.